# Pattern for preg_match

Tags: php, preg-match-all

I have a string contains the following pattern "[link:activate/$id/$test_code]" I need to get the word activate, $id and $test_code out of this when the pattern [link.....] occurs.

I also tried getting the inside items by using grouping but only gets active and $test_code couldn't get $id. Please help me to get all the parameter and action name in array.

Below is my code and output

## Code

```
function match_test()
{
    $string  =  "Sample string contains [link:activate/\$id/\$test_code] again [link:anotheraction/\$key/\$second_param]]] also how the other ationc like [link:action] works";
    $pattern = '/\[link:([a-z\_]+)(\/\$[a-z\_]+)+\]/i';
    preg_match_all($pattern,$string,$matches);
    print_r($matches);
}
```

## Output

```
    Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [0] => [link:activate/$id/$test_code]
                [1] => [link:anotheraction/$key/$second_param]
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [0] => activate
                [1] => anotheraction
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [0] => /$test_code
                [1] => /$second_param
            )

    )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$subject = <<<'LOD'
Sample string contains [link:activate/$id/$test_code] again [link:anotheraction/$key/$second_param]]] also how the other ationc like [link:action] works
LOD;
$pattern = '~\[link:([a-z_]+)((?:/\$[a-z_]+)*)]~i';
preg_match_all($pattern, $subject, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

if you need to have `\$id` and `\$test_code` separated you can use this instead:

```
$pattern = '~\[link:([a-z_]+)(/\$[a-z_]+)?(/\$[a-z_]+)?]~i';
```

Comment: It does give all the variable in one element.    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => [link:activate/$id/$test_code]
            [1] => [link:anotheraction/$key/$second_param]
            [2] => [link:action]
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => activate
            [1] => anotheraction
            [2] => action
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => /$id/$test_code
            [1] => /$key/$second_param
            [2] => 
        )

Comment: @Nish: you need to have `/$id/$test_code` separated in `$id` and `$test_code`?

Comment: yes, is it posible to do in one regular expression? Without doing that in second one?

Comment: @Nish: I don't understand your question, the second pattern does this! use it instead of the first.

Comment: Thank you @Casimir et Hippolyte

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

`/\[link:([\w\d]+)\/(\$[\w\d]+)\/(\$[\w\d]+)\]/`

Edit:

Also the problem with your expression is this part:
`(\/\$[a-z\_]+)+`

Although you have repeated the group, the match will only return one because it is still only one group declaration.  The regex won't invent matching group numbers for you (Not that i've ever seen anyway).

Comment: Still I am not getting $id in the matched values. Only getting the $test_code

Comment: I just tested it at: http://gskinner.com/RegExr/
using that expression (without the wrapping slashes), both of your strings, and using the `replace` tool to replace the pattern with $1, $2, and $3, worked fine.